# What does "moved" mean in these definitions?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

These are definitions for the adjective "divided" which I looked up in the dictionary because I stumbled upon the phrase "divided loyalties" which I didn't understand.

"divided" adj:

-3. **Moved** by conflicting interests, emotions, or activities: *divided loyalties*. (American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language)

-b
: directed or **moved** toward conflicting interests, states, or objects
*divided loyalties* (Merriam-Webster)

I know that "loyalties" means:

feeling or attitude of devoted attachment and affection: *My loyalties lie with my family.*

**So what does it mean that "loyalties are moved"?**

Comment: It doesn't say that the loyalties are moved.  It says that the subject is moved by divided loyalties.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @strangdon loyalties are moved because they are divided(definition of divided at the top says that divided means moved)

Comment: @StaticBounce: no, loyalties are not moved. _Moved_ in both these definitions refer to people (or to groups of people or organisations). OED definition 1a: "Affected by emotion; emotionally touched, swayed, or impressed" - this use is specifically the "swayed or impressed" part of that definition.

Comment: @ColinFine I'm actually with Static on this one. In the phrase "divided loyalties", the adjective "divided" modifies the noun "loyalties", and [AHD's definition of "divided"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=divided) is "moved by . . .". Therefore, the loyalties are described as "moved by . . .". Similar for [M-W's definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divided). (They're bad definitions, IMO.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using "*moved*" In a sense other than being physically moved from onme place to another. Some relevant definitions:

- [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/moved):

> having strong feelings of sadness or sympathy, because of something someone has said or done:

- [Merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/move) Entry 2 (transitive verb)

> (sense 2c)  to put into activity or rouse up from inactivity; *news that moved them from their torpor*

> (Sense 4) to prompt or rouse to the doing of something : persuade;, *the report moved us to take action*

> (Sense 5a) to stir the emotions, feelings, or passions of; *deeply moved by such kindness*

So when the definition said:

> **Moved** by conflicting interests, emotions, or activities

it meant that a person was being motivated by conflicting interests, and so on, or being induced to act by such interests.